# Issues with appending to list - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm building a simple web scraping script to get my feet wet with python.
I'm hitting a little but of an issue with the following

```
#Create 3 different lists to populate.
mails = []
phones = []
webs = []

def go_get_info(info):
    for item in info:
        #email = (item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[0].text).strip()
        #phone = (item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[1].text).strip()                                                                                                          
        www = (item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[2].text).strip()
        if not www:
                webs.append("empty")
        else:
                webs.append(www)
```

The idea is that I would get email, phone, and web address into each of the three lists, zip them togther and then iterate through and write to CSV.

The only value here that I seem to have an issue with is www **(and so as you can see I've left it uncommented). **I've also tried to mitigate the issue by adding an empty condition.****

When I run the script that calls this function, I am returned the following

```
± |add-csv-support U:1 ?:1 ✗| → python scrape.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 55, in <module>
    go_retrieve_contact(get_venue_link_list(links))
  File "scrape.py", line 30, in go_retrieve_contact
    go_get_info(info)
  File "scrape.py", line 43, in go_get_info
    www = (item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[2].text).strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It makes sense to me that the issue is either with the value being returned or the lack of a value.  I've googled but couldn't find a complete solution.

What could I do in this case to

A) Better understand whats happening and debug better.

B) Solve the problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I think `find_all` returns a list of matches.  If index 2 is out of bounds, then that means it found less than 3 matches.  Save the result to a variable, then check the length *before* trying to access elements that aren't there.  Then you can decide how you want to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to the fourth element (`item.contents[3]`) or the 3rd element(`find_all(...)[2]`) and one of those 2 arrays does not have that many elements, which is what `list index out of range` means.

```
www = (item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[2].text).strip()
```

Since this is part of a scraping tool, you might want to write a line that checks how many elements you are getting in your find_all by nesting it in a `if len((...).find_all(...)) >= 3` statement or use `try except`